# laravel 5 main domain with www and also recognize sub domains

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel-5

I have domain as example.dev and i want to redirect it to www.example.dev in laravel 5. In local environment i have setup virtual host as example.dev and also setup it's alias as www.example.dev.

my .htaccess file on laravel 5 looks like this.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
RewriteBase "/"
```

and my routes file in laravel looks like this.

```
Route::group(array('domain' => 'example.dev'), function()
{
Route::get('/', function() {
    return "I'm root!";
});
});

Route::group(array('domain' => '{sub}.example.dev'), function()
{
Route::get('/', function($sub) {

    return "I'm ".$sub." subdomain";
});
});
```

now if i visit at example.dev, i get output as

> I'm root

and if i visit at something.example.dev, i get

> I'm something subdomain

and if i visit at www.example.dev, i get this...

> I'm www subdomain

what i could think of is to define another custom domain group with **www** but this is not so good i believe or not good practice. i tried with some modification in my .htaccess file as follow after **RewriteEngine On**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

and now if i visit example.dev it redirect be at www.example.dev but still the output is

> I'm www subdomain

then i changes my first routing group from example.dev to www.example.dev and it **worked!** but i just need to know if this is the right way to do this or not? or using groups for multiple sub-domains is the only way ? and do you know any easy and best way to check subdomains from database through controller so i will check it that subdomain exists then serve with it's view otherwise pass not found error. i know somewhere it can be done with filter and using **before** but don't know exactly!

help would be really appreciated. 
thanks :)

Comment: Why not just check for `if($sub == "www")` in your route group closure?

Comment: @Joe so you mean in my second group where i'm checking for any subdomain, i check as 'if($sub == "www")' then serve my home content (i'm root!!)? then should i delete my first group ?

Comment: i deleted my first group and make my second domain group as follow, but getting output as **I'm www subdomain**


`Route::group(array('domain' => '{sub}.bedivilla.dev'), function($sub)
{
    if($sub == "www"){
     return "I'm root!";
    }

    Route::get('/', function($sub) {
        return "I'm ".$sub." subdomain" ;
    });
});`

Comment: I would go for the htaccess approach. in case of search engines, it's better to have just one domain for a website. i.e. a permanent redirect to the www subdomain makes sense if you use www.example.com on your business cards or vice versa.

Comment: @RaphaelMüller in the point of SEO i have very good experience more than four years but in this case i'm having problem to setup my routes in laravel.

Answer (score 1):

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{sub}.example.dev'), function($sub)
{
    if($sub == 'www' || $sub == ''){
        Route::get('/',function(){
            return "I'm root!";
        });
    }
    else{
        Route::get('/', function($sub) {
            return "I'm ".$sub." subdomain";
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: in your code above you forgot to pass `$sub` as argument in route group function so it works in if statement. i've tried with that code but still the output for www.example.dev is **I'm www subdomain**